# animate multiple paths in svg without using css

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-animate

I have an svg file with number of paths. Let this be the file structure :

```
<g>
 <path>......</path>
 <path>......</path>
 <path>......</path>
 <path>......</path>
 <path>......</path>
 <path>......</path>
</g>
```

I want to animate all these paths together without using css, somewhat like this:

```
<animate
  attributeName="fill-opacity" 
  from="0" 
  to="1" 
  dur="2s" 
  begin="3s"
  fill="freeze" />
```

I don't want to aim each path specifically.

Answer (score 5):

All you need to do is put your `<animate>` in the group so that you target the group's `fill-opacity` value.  The paths will inherit that opacity.

```html
<svg>
  <g fill-opacity="0">
    <animate
      attributeName="fill-opacity" 
      from="0" 
      to="1" 
      dur="2s" 
      begin="0s"
      fill="freeze" />

    <path d="M0,0 L100,0 L50,150 Z" fill="red"/>
    <path d="M150,0 L200,150 L100,150 Z" fill="limegreen"/>
    <path d="M200,0 L300,0 L250,150 Z" fill="purple"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```